# Proof that $\left(\frac{{\pi}^n}{nn!}\right)_{n\ge 1}$ is a decreasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, factorial

It seems that
$$\left(\frac{{\pi}^n}{nn!}\right)_{n\ge 1}$$
is a decreasing sequence. How can I prove it?

I noticed that replacing $\pi$ by $2\pi$ makes the sequence *increasing* for a bit, and removing the $n$ in front of $n!$ makes the sequence increasing for a bit as well. The problem in hand seems quite non-trivial and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $a_n$ for the $n$th term. Then $a_{n+1}/a_n=n\pi/(n+1)^2$, and we need this to be always less than $1$. This is clearly true for $n\geq 3$ since $n\pi/(n+1)^2<\pi/(n+1)\leq \pi/4$. So we just need to check $n=1,2$ for which we get $\pi/4$ and $2\pi/9$ respectively.

(For the corresponding sequence with $2\pi$ you'd need $n\pi/(n+1)^2<1/2$, which isn't true for small values.)

Comment: Note that the case $n=0$ (i.e. $a_1/a_0=0$) is a little out of scope, since $a_0$ is not defined in the sequence, but Especially Lime is probably interpreting $a_0$ to be $+\infty$.

Comment: @Milten yes, I was being silly and only needed to check 1 and 2.